# I need url rewriting conversion from htaccess to NGINX

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I try convert this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

to NGINX

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/  /index.php?_route=$uri;
}
```

but does not work

if work you will see json file on http://test.bktvnews.com/data/menu/footer
http://test.bktvnews.com/data/

Comment: I see `_route_=` in Apache and `_route=` in nginx. Also, Apache rewrites only if there is no query part. And, still, show full nginx server config.

Comment: BTW, `$uri` in nginx starts with `/`.

Comment: thx, i change this but still not working
what you mean about / and $url

Comment: He means that in htaccess $1 will be `data/menu/folder`, but in nginx $uri is `/data/menu/folder` - may be it's important for your application. And can you tell more about "does not work".

Answer (score -1):

You can convert with this online tool.
http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

This is your .htaccess to nginx

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.)\?$ /index.php?route=$1 break;
    }
}
```